# Printing Using Visual Basic 2005

Tags: vb.net, printing

I tried asking my friend how to print using Visual Basic 2005... He told me that there's no way to print the form using vb2005. I'm a newbie in vb2005 and I just want to ask if there's any Print Document tool for this application? If so then kindly give me a link to download it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the System.Drawing.Printing namespace ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing ) should be enough to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is almost correct. In early version of VB.NET there was no easy way to print the form like there used to be in VB6. From VS2008 onwards you can use the `PrintForm` component found in the VisualBasic PowerPacks Toolbox section

Have a look at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb690938%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more information